# Output a string thats assigned to an element in a double Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Hey I have a pretty simple question to be answered. I assigned elements of my array to string values. I want my code to output the string instead of the element value. Here is an example:

`double stock[5] = {249.99,49.99,13.99,449.99,59.99};
    double Beats = stock[0]; 
    double iPod = stock[1]; 
    std::cout << "Okay, you purchased " << stock[0] << endl;`

The output I would like is "Okay, you purchased Beats." . The output I recieve is "Okay, you purchased 249.99."

How can I make it print the string instead of the value? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What string? Could you show us the output you want?

Comment: Mike is asking for Beats or iPod, it looks like that is what he wants to print in his code example, this isn't a string, he wants the name of the variable.

Comment: Then he should make a container of strings, not of numbers.

Comment: Where are your strings? Are you referring to the variable names `Beats` and `iPod`?

Comment: Do I make Beats & iPod sting data types instead of double?

Comment: No. That would lose their ability to store stock[0]. What you want is an object that can store both. ie. item Beats = new item("Beats", stock[0]); Then you can call  std::cout << "Okay, you purchased " << Beats.name << endl; or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely want some kind of container, be it a `struct`, `class` or `pair`. Here's an example (using a `pair`):

```
#include <utility>
#include <string>

...

std::pair <std::string,double> stock [5];
stock[0]=std::make_pair("Beats",249.99);

...

std::cout << "Okay, you purchased " << stock[0].first << "." << endl;
```

This will output what you want ("Okay, you purchased Beats.").

You can use `stock[i].first` to access the first element (the name, as a string), and `stock[i].second` to access the second element (the value, as a double).

Answer (score 1):

```
string items[5] = {"Beats", "iPod", "CD", "Vinyl", "Sheet"};
std::cout << "Okay, you purchased " << items[0] << endl;
```

If you want to maintain the numbers (i.e `stock`) also, you need something a little more sophisticated.

Answer (score -1):

I assume you need to display what item has been purchased and at what price. If so, may be you need something like following.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct item_struct
{
    std::string item;
    double price;
    item_struct(string _item, double _price)
    {
        item = _item;
        price = _price;
    }
};

int main() {

    item_struct *stock[5] = {new item_struct("Beats", 249.99),
                                new item_struct("iPod", 49.99),
                                new item_struct("CD", 13.99),
                                new item_struct("iPone", 899.99),
                                new item_struct("Nexus 5", 499.99)
                                };

    std::cout << "Okay, you purchased " << stock[0]->item << endl;

    std::cout << "Okay, you purchased " << stock[3]->item
                << " at the price of " << stock[3]->price
                << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
Okay, you purchased Beats
Okay, you purchased iPone at the price of 899.99
```